# Testing website on localhost server for iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, localhost

What I'm looking to do is preview what I've built on a custom localhost server (set up with Mamp Pro) on my iphone or ipad. The localhost is under http://devsite:8888 and not http://localhost:8888.

I've tried the instructions for something similar found [here](http://nclud.com/sketchbook/view-local-websites-iphone-ipad/). The result was being able to see the files but it was just the list of the files on the server and not picking up index.php—no previews enabled. I've triple checked to make sure I have a proper index in the root directory as well.

Added /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file
https://gist.github.com/07223bf788ef1e2e1411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your .htaccess or httpd.conf (usually `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` on OSX):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If that is put in .htaccess be sure that somewhere in httpd.conf (or whatever customm config file for the web server) you have this (replace `/var/www/html` with the directory where your .htaccess file is):

```
## These lines can go anywhere in the main config file:
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Also, make sure your `/etc/hosts` file includes:

```
127.0.0.1       devsite
# Or whatever your local computers IP is:
# 192.164.2.164  devsite
```

so that the hostname will resolve properly.

---

Edit:

From the comments, it sounds like your virtual hosts may need additional configuration.  Can you put the contents of the `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file in your question?

Comment: My hosts file includes this already:

    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1 localhost
    
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    
    ::1             localhost
     
    fe80::1%lo0 localhost
    
    127.0.0.1 devsite_main
    
    127.0.0.1 devsite


Is there anything out of place with this? It doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: Did you set the: `DirectoryIndex index.php`?  You can put that line in a file named `.htaccess` inside the directory that contains the `index.php` file.

Comment: And you have set `AllowOverride All` in a `.conf` file in a `<Directory "...">` section?

Comment: Yep, I set that as well in "/etc/apache2/httpd.conf". When I hit the site on iphone, I see just the index list of files. If I use :8888 after the IP I get localhost, which does work, but it's a different site.

Comment: Sounds like your virtual hosts need adjusting.  Can you put the contents of the `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file in your question?

Comment: Added /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file
https://gist.github.com/07223bf788ef1e2e1411