# Testing Django website on iphone

Tags: iphone, django

I apologize for such a beginner question, but I'm stuck. I'm starting learn web development and I want to test out something I am hosting locally using Django runserver command. I would like to test it on my iPhone. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519814/testing-website-on-localhost-server-for-iphone-and-ipad), I just need to point my iPhone to my Windows 7 ip address (which I found through ipconfig).  When I try to, I get the error: "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding" (a time-out).

Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: Maybe silly question, but is the iPhone on Wi-Fi(the same network as your server)?

Comment: http://davidwilson.me/2013/08/18/Testing-Django-on-mobile-device-locally.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to using the correct IP, your runserver command should listen on 0.0.0.0(all IPs).

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 9):

Below steps  worked for me on MAC OS 10.10.3

1. python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
2. in terminal window "ipconfig getifaddr en0" returned IP address 10.0.1.22
3. open browser in Iphone/Ipad "http://10.0.1.22:8000"

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the IP address **AND** port that the `runserver` is running on... this is usually `:8080` or whatever number that follows the IP it reports when it runs the server.

so if the `runserver` command reports...

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

then if your IP is `192.168.0.2` use...

`http://192.168.0.2:8000/`

If for some reason you want to set the port manually, `runserver [port]` works...

Comment: Also make sure you aren't limiting access to your Win7 with firewall settings.

Comment: I've added the port and am getting the same error. I went to firewall and practically allowed everything just to see if that was the issue, but it's still not working. Is there anything else I could check?

Comment: actually I just turned my firewall off and my iPhone won't connect to the server (different error)

Answer (score 0):

FOR WINDOWS USERS WHO MIGHT RUN INTO THE SAME PROBLEM.

STEP 1: run **python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000**

STEP 2: run **ipconfig** on your windows' computer cmd

STEP 3: in your **settings.py** file change this line of code like this **ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']**

STEP 4: type http:// then your ip address that you got from STEP 2 then : and then port 8000, something like this **(http://192.168.0.2:8000/)**, but the ip address should be your computer ip address.