# How to connect iphone to a local server running on mac?

Tags: ios, django, iphone, ip-address

I am running a django server at localhost:8000  to accces it from iPhone i had connected the iphone and mac to the same network.

```
 ifconfig |grep inet
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
inet 127.94.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
inet 127.94.0.2 netmask 0xff000000 
inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
inet6 fe80::10a0:e008:9d34:5f7e%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x6 
inet 192.168.43.234 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
inet6 2401:4900:2320:f3e9:10a0:ab34:c773:1104 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
inet6 2401:4900:2320:f3e9:b444:77e0:94f:8ccc prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
inet6 fe80::b4ed:bff:feba:10c2%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
inet6 fe80::b4ed:bff:feba:10c2%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
inet6 fe80::54e:e417:7879:b351%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
inet6 fe80::203b:4e44:1f36:a04c%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10 
inet6 fe80::eaa6:a7d3:cf35:3fe1%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x11 
inet6 fe80::7604:df44:d8c4:65be%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
inet6 fe80::3e0f:e8c3:e7a:f96c%utun4 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
inet6 fe80::3719:2c00:294b:88be%utun5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x16
```

After running the ifconfig command i took out the ip adress of the mac  i.e. 192.168.43.234. And using this address in safari i am not able to access the server from iphone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing Django website on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667179/testing-django-website-on-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access it by running Django with this command :
`python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000`

Then go to `192.168.43.234:8000` on your phone.

Comment: It worked. But i am not able to  access the the server after restarting the computer. the django server is running like suggested but still i am not able to access the server on iphone. Firewall is also off